# Equal and opposite Voltages applied across 2 resistors of equal Value

Tags: voltage-divider

Take a look at this picture here:

[image]

Please note that the two resistors are equal in size.

Here it says that the voltage at Point TP3 is zero volts. I do not understand how that is.
The creator of this image says in a video that this is because the Voltage at Point TP2 (-6V) and TP8 (+6V) cancel each other out.

Is he right? Do they cancel each other out?

Here is the link to the youtube video: watch?v=tsrAP8EgcbQ

****EDIT****

So here is my scribble:[image]

My understanding is that the Voltage "AB" (the voltage above R2) will be feed to the amplifier. In the first picture i posted that would be the voltage "TP3TP8".

So the voltage between the point A and the point B will be 0 volts?

***Edit***

Thanks for the help. Something must be wrong with my understanding of voltages. I have now something to work with.

Again thank you!

Comment: You might consider placing negative voltage sources on the bottom and positive on top of your diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the voltages do not "cancel out", it's a a bad way to think about it. But we can show that the voltage at TP3 is in fact 0, assuming the two resistances are equal.

Look at my poor scribble below. Let's do a KCL analysis at the TP3 junction. I3, the current going into the OpAmp is 0, because that is an assumption of ideal op-amps. We are only left with two currents I1 an I2 which must be equal. Now substituting the equations with voltages using I = V/R we can see that TP3 voltage must be 0 volts.

[image]

Comment: What you say makes sense. I got something to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Rather than "cancel each other out", I would say that the two resistors form a voltage divider between TP2 (-6V) and TP3 (+6V).

If the two resistors are of equal value, the mid-point must be half way between the two end voltages.  Since the end voltages are equal, but opposite polarity, the mid-point must be zero volts.

This assumes that the amplifier input does not source or sink any current.  If it does source or sink current, the current in the two resistors, and therefore the voltage across them, will be affected by that current, so the mid-point will not be zero volts.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as both resistors being between 12V and 0V - simple voltage divider, you get 6V at the node TP3, which is thus 6V apart from both rails (TP2 and TP8). Equal voltage across both equal resistors is a given when they both have the same current through them (which is an absolute given in the circuit shown). Whatever voltages you put on TP2 and TP8 - TP3 is always going to be an equal amount apart from both. At 6V and -6V, 0V is the value where it will be 6V apart from them.

BTW, if you are building this circuit in practice: This will fail if you use high value (say 100s of Kiloohms) resistors and an Opamp that needs a high input bias current.